# Lost products from the cart when you refresh the page: Magento 2

Tags: magento2

When you go to checkout there is a product, but you only need to refresh the page or switch from checkout to any other page, then the goods will disappear, such a feeling that it removes it from the session, who faced this problem?

Comment: Have you checked your session related configurations? Try increasing the session life time?

Comment: Yes, using the standard basket.
It all worked fine.
I did not install any new modules.

Comment: It is not related to any modules. It is related to your session configuration

Comment: And where can I see in the admin, the life of the session?

Comment: You can find the current value of session lifetime by phpinfo() https://prnt.sc/n6tpe6. So try increasing its value in php.ini file to see if your problem gets solved. Are you finding this error for both guest and registered users or for any particular one?

Comment: For unauthorized users.
For authorized users, another problem has arisen, in the basket it shows that there is a product, but when you switch to it it shows that it is empty.

Comment: So try to increase the session lifetime. If so the issue persists after increasing the session value troubleshoot cookie settings and values.